# sql access inner join of 4 tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I am new to sql and I am trying to join 4 tables together but just cant get the hang of it.
I am trying to do this with an inner join but I always get an syntax error with access.

```
SELECT * 
from kdst,aufpos 
inner join( artst inner join vert on kdst.vertreter = vert.vertnr)
on aufpos.artnr = artst.artnr;
```

This is my code but it does not work. I dont know what to do anymore, I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Is there any reason why you cannot use the MS Access query design window to build this query?

Comment: I dont know. But I am supposed to do this in sql.

Comment: You have a strange mix of explicit and implicit inner joins.  what condition joins `aufpos` to the other tables?  I see how `artst` joins `aufpos`, but not the condition that links it back to `kdst, vert`.

Comment: The query design window creates SQL. Build the query then switch to sql view.

Comment: Post your table schema if you can.

Comment: I did not vote to close this as off-topic, I voted to move it to SuperUser. Using queries is important in development in MS Access, but this question seemed to be on a borderline between using MS Access and developing in MS Access. If it does not belong on SuperUser, then it must belong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build using the query design window

[image: access query design window]

Then switch to sql view

[image: sql view]

Comment: Thank you! Do you maybe have a tutorial or guide on how to use it?

Comment: You can search for query design window, for example, http://www.techrepublic.com/article/10-tips-for-working-efficiently-in-access-query-design-window/6172886. You can use the F1 (Help) Key and you can try out the query design wizards.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * 
From table1 t1
Inner join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.fkid
Inner join table3 t3 on t1.id = t3.fkid
...
```

This is if you want to join multiple tables to the same parent table (`table1`). `Fkid` is the column of the foreign key field that refers to the primary key of the parent table.

Comment: Oh, and I'd be very careful using a select *. Much better to select only the fields from each table that you need (e.g. t2.foo, t3.bar).

Comment: @Remou: why won't it work when it is what your answer is showing?

Comment: My illustration shows two tables, once you go above two tables, you need parentheses on your joins. Access is very fussy about it, which is why it is nearly always best for someone new to Access to use the query design window.

Comment: Whoops didn't catch the Access part. Been a while since I've touched that. Not sure I would have noticed the parens issue.