# How do I find a match or lookup in a query?

Tags: sql, ms-access, lookup

Moving from Excel to Access and having a little difficulty, am hoping someone can help me out.

I have a table full of encounter data (`Table: EncData`); part of that data is the date of the encounter (`Column: EncDateTime`).

In my query, I need to have a column that displays if that date is a *Weekend*, *Weekday*, or *Holiday*.  The Weekend and Weekday part is not a problem for me (have had luck with `Format()`).  Am struggling with how to match the Encounter Date to a Holiday lookup table (`Table: Holidays`).

In Excel, I used a formula I used `Match()` to see if it returned a holiday.  How do I do this in Access?

```
TABLE: Holidays
ID__________HolidayDate
1           10/8/2012
2           9/3/2012

TABLE: EncData
ID__________EncDateTime__________________More Data
12          10/08/2012 09:15:12 AM       (etc)
```

In my query (which is displaying information from the `EncData` table), I've been playing around with DLookup without success just to see if I can find a match:

```
DLookup("HolidayDate", "Holidays", "HolidayDate =" & Format([EncDateTime],"mm/dd/yyyy"))
```

Even though this is not working, I can tell it's also really slow.

Know very little about SQL but I think this should be a cinch.

Thanks

Comment: Some reading on joins http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/  and some notes on MS Access queries http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13335236/sql-access-inner-join-of-4-tables/13335314#13335314. Access also has wizards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dates in SQL are represented as #year/month/day#, eg. today's date would be #2012/11/19#, and to make DLookup work you have to use this syntax:

```
DLookup("HolidayDate", "Holidays", "HolidayDate=" & Format([EncDateTime],"\#yyyy/mm/dd\#"))
```

to check if today is holiday, you could use this:

```
DLookup("HolidayDate", "Holidays", "HolidayDate=" & Format(Date(),"\#yyyy/mm/dd\#"))
```

Yes, DLookup is slow, you should not use it in a query. To check if `EncDateTime` is a holiday, you should join `EncData` and `Holidays` togheter, with this SQL Code:

```
SELECT EncData.*
FROM EncData INNER JOIN Holidays ON EncData.EncDateTime = Holidays.HolidayDate
```

This should return all EncData rows that are hoildays. It should, but it probably doesn't. Notice that EncDateTime contains not only the date, but also the time, so it doesn't match with HolidayDate that contains just the date. This works instead:

```
SELECT EncData.*
FROM EncData INNER JOIN Holidays ON DateValue(EncData.EncDateTime) = Holidays.HolidayDate
```

And to extract all the rows in EncData, not just the holidays?

```
SELECT EncData.*, Holidays.HolidayDate
FROM EncData LEFT JOIN Holidays ON DateValue(EncData.EncDateTime) = Holidays.HolidayDate
```

Notice that when HolidayDate contains a date only when that day is holiday, otherwise it will be NULL.

These are just some basic ideas to start. But don't forget that you cans use wizards to make your query, then you can always see how your SQL code looks like.

Comment: Thanks so much for the lesson - I learned enough to get it to work.  I posted my final code below.  Am using an `IIf` statement - not sure if that is most efficient but its what I know for now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using [fthiella](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13462999/181902)'s code suggestions here is what I finally came up with using `IIf` statements to determine if the date was a *Holiday*, *Weekday*, or *Weekend*.

```
SELECT EncData.*, 
IIf(ISNULL(Holidays.HolidayDate),IIf(Weekday(EncData.EncDateTime) = 1 or Weekday(EncData.EncDateTime) = 7,"Weekend","Weekday"),"Holiday") AS [DayType]
FROM EncData
LEFT JOIN Holidays ON DateValue(EncData.EncDateTime)=Holidays.HolidayDate;
```

I am not sure if I should be using `CASE` statements instead (are they faster?) but this is working for the time being.  Thanks!